# How to perform some arithmetic calculation on last record of ID in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have below data in my table, I want to do some arithmetic operation in SQL query when it reach on last record of each id which is highlighed in bold in below table.

Table Name : Invoices

```
ID       Amount  Tax_Amount
-------------------------------
500324    $46.5   0.6
500324    $46.5   0.6
500324    $46.5   2.01 --> Need to do some arithmetic operation here
500326    $46.5   0.6   
500326    $46.5   0.6   
500326    $46.5   0.6   
500326    $46.5   2.01 -->Need to do some arithmetic operation here
500327    $46.5   0.6   
500327    $46.5   2.01 -->Need to do some arithmetic operation here
```

How to write a SQL query which identify that it is last record of particulate ID.

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: How do you know the highlighted id is the last record?

Comment: Rows in a table are ***not*** "sorted". You have to have some column that determines the order of the rows otherwise there is no such thing as "the last row". And you need to tell us which DBMS you are using. Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: This is the my question , how can SQL query know that it reach on last record of that id?

Comment: As I said: you need some column that defines the order of those rows. if you don't have it, there is no such thing as "the last row"

Comment: Could you, please, provide more detail on the exact calculation, you want to do?

Comment: And it would probably help to see your actually expected output for the above rows. (Just update your question accordingly.)

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you have a unique key. Assume you have such column (lets call it RECORD_ID).
In this case the following query will work for you:

```
UPDATE TableName 
SET Tax_Amount = MATH_FUNCTION(Tax_Amount) 
WHERE RECORD_ID = (SELECT RECORD_ID FROM TableName WHERE RECORD_ID = MAX(RECORD_ID));
```

If you want just show the calculated value (without modifying it) on SELECT:

```
SELECT ID,Amoun,      CASE 
     WHEN RECORD_ID = MAX(RECORD_ID) THEN MATH_FUNCTION(TaxAmount)
     ELSE TaxAmount
  END AS TaxAmount
FROM TableName
```

It might be some syntax issues as I have no SQL Server.

Additionally you can use database specific functions to make the query more optimal.

MATH_FUNCTION can be one of the database_specific or standard function or combination of functions. For MySQL you can find the list of functions:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-functions.html

Comment: I need all 9 records in result, additionally need to some arithmetic operation when it reach on last record of particulate ID. so in my example, I need to do some calculation 3 time , and get final result which return all 9 rows. Please note that, it is not mandatory that all records are sorted.

Comment: Yes, I need select query.

Comment: See the update. I added the select statement. Is it what you need?

Comment: Yes, but how can we know that this is Max Record_ID of particulate ID, We need here some grouping and get count and then compare somehow but don't know how?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL Server 2008 or later version, you can use the [ROLLUP()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495.aspx) GROUP BY function and add a Total line:

```
SELECT
  ID= ISNULL(ID, 'Total'),
  Amount= Amount,
  Tax_Amount_Total = SUM(Tax_Amount)
FROM Invoices
GROUP BY ROLLUP(ID, Amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rollup in SQL Server to summarize your data.

- [Summarizing Data Using ROLLUP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305(v=sql.90).aspx)
- [Using GROUP BY with ROLLUP, CUBE, and GROUPING SETS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx)